# Proximal Point of the absolute value function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, proximal-operators

Absolute value function is defined as follows:
\begin{equation*}
   f(x) = |x| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  -x & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

Prox of $|x|$ is

\begin{equation*}
   \text{prox}_{|\cdot|}^{\gamma}(x) = \text{argmin}_{y \in \mathcal{H}} 
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  y + \frac{1}{2\gamma} ||y-x||^2 & \mbox{if } y \geq 0 \\
  -y + \frac{1}{2\gamma} ||y-x||^2& \mbox{if } y < 0
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

Since the objective function of the minization problem is convex, the first order condition of optimality of a convex function is applied to get the minimizing point $y$.

Derivate w.r.t $y$ and using first order condition, $1+ \frac{1}{\gamma} (y -x) = 0 $ implies that the minimizer (proximal point) is $y = x - \gamma$ when $x - \gamma \ge 0$

Similary, $ -1+ \frac{1}{\gamma} (y -x) = 0 $ implies that the proximal point is $y = x + \gamma$ when $x < -\gamma$

\begin{equation*}
   \text{prox}_{|\cdot|}^{\gamma}(x) = 
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x - \gamma & \mbox{if } x \geq \gamma \\
  x + \gamma & \mbox{if } x \leq -\gamma \\
  ? & \mbox{if } |x| < \gamma \\
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

**Question: When $|x| < \gamma $ then what is the proximal point of the absolute value function?.**

Comment: Let’s assume $x > 0$. In this case, there is no possible benefit in choosing $y$ to be negative. So we can restrict our attention to nonnegative values of $y$. The function we are minimizing is $y + \frac{1}{2\gamma}(y - x)^2$. This is a quadratic function of a single variable $y$. You know how to minimize a quadratic function of a single variable — in fact, you’ve been able to do this ever since taking pre-calculus. The graph of a quadratic function is a parabola so you can draw a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote by $g^\gamma(y)$ the function that you are interested in minimizing. If $\vert x \vert < \gamma,$ then the derivative of $g^\gamma$ is always non-zero. However, we know that a proximal point must exist since $g^\gamma$ is convex, so it follows that the minimizing value of $g^\gamma$ must be exactly the point of non-differentiability of $g^\gamma,$ i.e. $\text{prox}^\gamma_{\vert \cdot \vert}(x) = 0$ when $\vert x \vert < \gamma.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Got it, the non-zero derivative is the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Precisely. You're most welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest, but not the most insightful derivation is provided via the Moreau decomposition. The convex conjugate of the (scaled) absolute value $f(x) = \gamma |x|$ is the indicator of the (scaled) bi-unit interval: $f^*(z) = \delta_{[-\gamma, \gamma]}(z)$. The proximal operator of an indicator is just a projection, and in this case:
$$
\operatorname{prox}_{f^*}(x) = \begin{cases}
x & -\gamma \leq x \leq \gamma \\
\gamma & x > \gamma \\
-\gamma & x < \gamma
\end{cases}
$$

By the Moreau decomposition theorem:
$$
\operatorname{prox}_{f}(x) = x - \operatorname{prox}_{f^*}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & -\gamma \leq x \leq \gamma \\
x - \gamma & x > \gamma \\
x + \gamma & x < -\gamma
\end{cases}
$$